# (X ∩ Y) is open, where X is open and Y is not open

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I have a proof where it says the pre-images of an open set is open, but the open set is like this: (X ∩ Y) is open, where X is open and Y is not open.
Is the statement true?
How to prove it?

Comment: Is what statement true?

Comment: (X ∩ Y) is open, where X is open and Y is not open

Comment: Take $Y=[-10,10]$ and $x=(-1,1)$. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Google 'relative topology'.

Comment: and how could I prove it if I haven't take a course of Topology?, just Mathematical Analysis

Comment: @copper.hat: ... and then take $X=(−10,10)$ and $Y=[−1,1]$

Answer (score 1):

The theorem is false: notice $\mathbb R^2$ is open but a straight line $l$ is not open. Notice that $\mathbb R^2 \cap l$ is not open.

Comment: It is open in the subspace topology of the line, which is probably the context the theorem was used. The question is a bit lacking in that regard.

Comment: Hmm Good point, although in that case no proof would be requiere. It is by definition.